# What words would best describe the following terms?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

I was recently writing and found out that i couldn't use just one word to describe 4 people. For Example there is "Duo" for two people and "Trio" for three people. What terms can be used to describe more numbers?

Comment: Quartet, quintet, sextet, septet, octet, nonet and dectet (used mainly for musical ensembles).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Is there a term for these collective numbers, like ordinal and cardinal? I didn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

See [Quartet at Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/quartet), defined as

> A set of four people or things.

There is also [tetrad](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/tetrad) defined by Oxford dictionary as

> A group or set of four

But I'm afraid *tetrad* and *quartet* both are pretty set in ways they are used. Please refer other dictionaries as well, such as **Merriam Webster**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [***foursome***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foursome) to describe a group of four people, although the term is normally used in the context of a social gathering. The group does not necessarily have to be mixed-sex.

> **foursome**
>   ​
>   A group of four people meeting for a social activity, such as playing a game or having a meal:
>
> *Why don't we invite Caroline and Mark and make up a foursome?*

Cambridge Dictionary